# css part padding to float text by background image

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

I have backgound image and I use padding for text.

### JsBin:

[example](http://jsbin.com/egeqAMi/1/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 120px;
  background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat 10px 10px;
}
```

### Question:

**How can I use padding for only section of div ?**

### Output:

[image: output]

### My tryout:

Put empty `div`(100x100) where `background-image` should be, and add `float:left` to that blank `div`. But I am looking for CSS solution.
**Note that I have reasons to have image in background, not in div.**

Looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to take the place of the placeholder div and float it as you would an inline image.

http://jsbin.com/egeqAMi/4

```
#wrapper:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as background image can't be floated.

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/T3R3x/1/)**

```
#wrapper {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
  background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff') no-repeat 10px 10px;
}
#wrapper:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```